# Create a web application with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, definition-query

I have a question about ArcGIS server:

I want to make an application for users who can search for proper houses, like a house-finding engine, and I published my map to ArcGIS Server but how can I link my map to the ArcGIS JavaScript API and how can I write queries for my users?

For example: in my web application, I want the user to choose and select from drop boxes like price, region street or rooms?

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same road block and couldn't really get the results I was looking for without learning to code against the API.

We ended up going with Mango (http://mangomap.com) instead as it has a really good Google style attribute search available. There's also a query tool, which is pretty simple but works for our purpose.

I would share our app but it's private. Here's the map on Mango that we got our inspiration from: try typing "1270 BEAVERDAM RD" in the search bar at the top:

[Columbus County Land Records](http://columbusco.org/GIS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to jump into development, I highly recommend you taking a look at the [Web AppBuilder.](http://www.esri.com/software/web-appbuilder)

If you have ArcGIS for Desktop users, then you have licenses to setup an ArcGIS Online for Organisation account at no extra cost.

You register your ArcGIS Server services within your instance of ArcGIS Online.  You then add them to the Map Viewer within ArcGIS Online, configure any popups or bookmarks.

From there, you can add the WebMap into Web App Builder, and can configure the style and widgets that you want the users to have.  This includes a fairly powerful query widget, achieving the requirements you have.

At the time of writing, the Web AppBuilder is [available in Beta](https://betacommunity.esri.com) (get the Developer Edition), but this will be a part of ArcGIS Online in the not too distant future.

[Watch the video here.](http://video.esri.com/watch/3211/web-appbuilder-for-arcgis)

You can also enable [Feature Search](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-feature-search.htm) within ArcGIS Online for a Search Engine style experience.

Comment: yes I have ArcGIS for desktop, thank you I will try it